# Comic book title from the 1970s: robot army in transport planes

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots

I was very young, but some details have remained with me throughout the years and I always wanted to find it. I collected thousands of comics in the '90s, but never came across this one. It was an American newsstand comic sold in a UK newsagents, so very likely DC or Marvel; I'm guessing mid to late '70s.

A small group of heroes explore an abandoned airforce base and have backpack-mounted laser guns. They find jet fighters and a futuristic tank. Meanwhile, some evil AI or unseen villain sends some galaxy type jet cargo planes full of robot soldiers to attack them. Robots looked like astronauts, human size, very similar to how John Byrne drew mandroids.

Comment: Was this a single issue or a story spanning several issues?